# how can I display a list of links on a printed webpage

Tags: firefox

I am running ubuntu 20.04

I was wondering if it is possible when printing a webpage to have it also display a list of URLs (title and web address) ?

I used to be able to do this with internet explorer on Windows.

Comment: Where is the list coming from? Can you post a screenshot of what this looked like on Windows

Comment: I can't post a screenshot, because I don't have a Windows system. However, on IE on Windows when you did a "File --> Print" one of the available options was to include a list of links (which was printed as the last page)